# qgis wps client mime type not supported

Tags: qgis, wps, pywps

I'm trying to set up a WPS using PyWPS, but when I return GML the QGIS WPS client says process result unsupported MIME type.  Any idea why that is?

Comment: did you add the mime type webservers need that info to send back data in the right way see http://birdhouse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/wps.html

Answer (score 1):

The QGis WPS client has received little maintenance in recent years and a number of bugs have lingered. The number of MIME types it supports is fairly limited.

The simplest tools to test PyWPS are:

- [Wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) - for URL based requests
- [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) - for XML requests